# Ускорить код на python

Tags: python, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Написал программу для распределения людей по очереди. Всё работает, но меня не устраивает скорость программы. Не подскажете, как я могу ускорить свой код?
В первой строке дано число n (n≤10**5) - количество записей в журнале , то есть в массиве chronology может быть до 10 в 5 степени записей. Программа должна сработать за 3 секунды или меньше . В чём суть задания: 
В стране M есть город N. А в этом городе есть ЗАГС. И сегодня там случилась поломка ПО.

Были потеряны данные о заявлениях на регистрацию брака. Однако остался журнал прихода и вызова.

В журнале в хронологическом порядке записаны события двух видов:

Приход человека, желающего подать заявление. В журнале записана фамилия этого человека.
Объявление о вызове для утверждения заявления и проверки документов. В этом случае в журнале записано слово next .
В стране M принято, что супруги должны иметь одинаковую фамилию и начиная с прихода в ЗАГС для подачи заявления на регистрацию брака должны называть фамилию, которую будут носить после вступления в брак.
В городе N заявление на регистрацию брака принимается только в присутствии обоих будущих супругов.

После прихода в ЗАГС и внесения в журнал прихода и вызова соответствующей записи нужно встать в очередь. В случае, если один из будущих супругов пришёл раньше, то другой или другая присоединяются к будущей супруге или будущему супругу.

Когда вызывают следующую пару для утверждения заявления, может оказаться так, что первым в очереди стоит человек, будущая супруга или будущий супруг которого ещё не пришёл в ЗАГС. В этом случае на утверждение заявления идут те уже пришедшие в ЗАГС будущие супруги, которые находятся ближе всего к началу очереди. В случае, если в очереди нет ни одной пары, на вызов пойдёт первая появившаяся в очереди пара сразу после прихода второго супруга или супруги.

Ваша задача - восстановить по данной информации события, произошедшие в ЗАГСе города N за сегодня.
Формат входных данных:
В первой строке дано число n (n≤105) - количество записей в журнале.

В каждой из следующих n строк находится либо слово next, обозначающее вызов следующей пары, либо фамилия, состоящая из латинских букв и длиной не менее одного и не более двадцати символов.

Каждая из фамилий встречается в записях журнала не менее одного и не более двух раз.
Формат выходных данных:
В случае прихода человека, супруг или супруга которого ещё не пришёл или не пришла в ЗАГС, выведите перед фамилией этого человека 1st. Таким образом мы опишем событие становления в конец очереди нового пришедшего.

В случае прихода человека, супруг или супруга которого уже в ЗАГСе, выведите перед фамилией этого человека 2nd без кавычек. Таким образом мы опишем событие появления в очереди пары на месте, которое занял пришедший ранее супруг или супруга.

В случае объявления о вызове, выведите фамилию будущих супругов, чьё заявление будет утверждаться следующим. В случае, если на момент вызова в очереди нет ни одной пары будущих супругов, выводить фамилию будущих супругов, чьё заявление будет утверждаться следующим, следует только после появления этой пары в очереди. Если же до конца дня в ЗАГС не придёт ни одной пары, ничего выводить не нужно.

Не выводите лишние пробелы в конце или начале строк - это будет считаться за ошибку.

Для лучшего понимания формата выходных данных ознакомьтесь с примерами ниже.

```
#a = int(input())
chronology = ['next','Pit','Wait','Wait','Pit']
next = 0
answer = []
names = []
def find(aror):
    final = []
    for ar in aror:
        if ar[1] == 2:
            final.append(ar)
    if final:
        final = sorted(final,key=lambda x:x[2])
        return final[0]
    else:
        return None
def ocher(arr,num):
    global names
    i = 0
    while i < len(arr):
        if names[i][2] > num:
            names[i][2] -= 1
        i += 1
#for i in range(a):
    #chronology.append(input().strip())
for ch in chronology:
    if ch == 'next':
        fin = find(names)
        if fin:
            ocher(names,fin[2])
            answer.append(fin[0])
            names.remove(fin)
        else:
            next+=1
        continue
    h = True
    for na in names:
        if ch == na[0]:
            h = False
            answer.append('2nd ' + ch)
            na[1] += 1
    if h:
        if names:
            numb = sorted(names, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=True)[0][2]
            names.append([ch,1,numb + 1])
            answer.append('1st '+ch)
        else:
            names.append([ch, 1, 1])
            answer.append('1st ' + ch)
    if next > 0:
        fin = find(names)
        if fin:
            answer.append(fin[0])
            ocher(names,fin[2])
            names.remove(fin)
            next -= 1
for an in answer:
    print(an)
```

Comment: замените циклы на `map`, все `if` на словари - это должно ускорить код в несколько раз

Comment: 1) Какая скорость у вас, какая нужна? 2) Это просто код, но желающим его запустить придется вводить данные, причем не зная их, я к чему -- код должен быть минимально-запускаемым, т.е. лучше оформить код, чтобы любой мог его скопировать к себе и запустить, а не вводить данные. Например, с вашей стороны это убрать/закомментировать строчки с `input` и приложить заполненный `chronology`

Comment: вы хотите чтобы вам привели примеры ускорений базовых конструкций или решили задачу за вас?

Comment: примеры ускорений базовых конструкций

Answer (score 2):

Нужны две структуры для хранения данных:

`singles`: map (`dict)`, хранящий одиночек (фамилия; время), ключом является фамилия

`pairs`: очередь по приоритетам (по ключу времени) на основе бинарной кучи (см. `heapq`, но можно и вручную реализовать)

При этом сортировать очередь не нужно, порядок в ней поддерживается сам.

При поступлении фамилии она ищется в `singles`. Если нет - добавляется в него, если есть - удаляется и вставляется в `pairs`.

При запросе `next` снимается пара с вершины очереди `pairs`.

Таким образом, поиск в `singles`  будет происходить в среднем за `O(1)`, вставка в `pairs` и извлечение за `O(log(N))`

Набросок кода (из текста не очень ясно, что должно быть при многократном вызове при пустой очереди - я сделал накопление вызовов)

```
import heapq
chronology = ['next','AA','WW', 'BB','WW','BB','AA', 'next', 'next']    
singles = {}
pairs = []
wait = 0
for i, person in enumerate(chronology):
    if person == "next":
        if len(pairs) > 0:
            _, person = heapq.heappop(pairs)
            print(person)
        else:
            wait += 1
    else:
        if person in singles:
            t = singles[person]
            heapq.heappush(pairs, (t, person))
            print("2nd " + person)
            if (wait):
                _, person = heapq.heappop(pairs)
                print(person)
                wait -= 1
        else:
            singles[person] = i
            print("1st " + person)

1st AA
1st WW
1st BB
2nd WW
WW
2nd BB
2nd AA
AA
BB
```